# How do I remove the blank, scrollable space that exists in SharePoint 2013/SPOL?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

Recently I was doing some cross-browser testing and I started to notice that when you middle-clicked in the non-scrollable part of SharePoint webpages and pulled your mouse down, the "non-scrollable" part scrolls to reveal an empty white area. I was able to duplicate this error in the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome, but (of *course*) not Internet Explorer.

[image: Chrome 41, IE11, and Firefox 36 on demo]

I have tried several things to fix this problem -- removing paddings and margins, using `*:before,*:after {display:table-cell;content:''}` to force elements to not extend past their boundary boxes... basically everything I could think of. And yet the OOTB SharePoint demo still makes a mess.

The site I am trying to "fix" is internal, but I found another with the same problems at http://www.spsdemo.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Best response I've come up with:

Ignore it. You can't override bad Javascript with CSS. So even though this somehow wasn't an issue in SP2010, it's an issue with SP2013/SPOL. Also, file a bug with Microsoft...